# Show for algebraic $L/K$ if $L$ perfect, $K$ not necessarily perfect.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

I just need a simple example to show the statement, but Im doubting the one I thought of. I have proof that $K$ perfect $\iff L/K$ separable. So to show the statement we need some $L$ that is perfect and inseparable over $K$.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: $\Bbb F_5$ (which has characteristic $5$) is not an extension of $\Bbb F_4$ (which has characteristic $2$), and in fact every finite field is perfect.

Comment: @RobertShore But $\Bbb F_5^2 \neq \Bbb F_5$, why is it then perfect?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{F}_5^5 = \mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: @Riemann My bad, I meant $\Bbb F_4$. I cant edit so what I meant is $\Bbb F_4^2 \neq \Bbb F_4$

Comment: I just calculated and checked that $\mathbb{F}_4^2=\mathbb{F}_4$. For example I used construction $\mathbb{F}_4 := \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1) = \{0, 1, \alpha, \alpha+1\}$ where $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$.